# Bouncing ball around edges using action listener

Tags: java, graphics, actionlistener, graphics2d, actionevent

I am relatively new to java, i am trying to make an animation that when run the ball should move steadily around the enclosing rectangle, bouncing off the edges. When the STOP button is clicked the motion should freeze, and lastly when the GO button is pressed it should resume.

This is the code that i have produced so far:

```
import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;

// Does the drawing
class MyDrawing extends JPanel {

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

    g.setColor(Color.red);
    Ellipse2D.Double circle = new Ellipse2D.Double(300,120,50,50);
    g2.draw(circle);
    g2.fill(circle);
    Rectangle box1 = new Rectangle(10, 10, 380, 300);
    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g2.draw(box1);
}
}

//Produces window plus everything inside it
public class ControlledBall extends JFrame {
JButton flash = new JButton("Go");
JButton steady = new JButton("Stop");

JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
MyDrawing drawing = new MyDrawing();
Timer timer;
public ControlledBall(){
    panel.add(flash);
    panel.add(steady);
    this.add(panel,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    this.add(drawing,BorderLayout.CENTER);
    steady.addActionListener(new SteadyListener());
    flash.addActionListener(new MoveListener());
    timer = new Timer(500, new MoveListener());
    timer.start();

}


class MoveListener implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
        timer.start();
        move();
    }
}

//Stuck what to implement here
class SteadyListener implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){    
    }
} 

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame window = new ControlledBall();
    window.setSize(400,400);
    window.setTitle("Controlled Ball");
    window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    window.setVisible(true);

}
public void move() {

    long delay = 40;}
    private int x = 1;
    private int y = 1;
    private int dx = 3;
    private int dy = 2;{

    int dia = 30;
    Color color = Color.red;

    if(x + dx < 0 || x + dia + dx > getWidth()) {
        dx *= -1;
        color = Color.red;
    }
    if(y + dy < 0 || y + dia + dy > getHeight()) {
        dy *= -1;
        color = Color.red;
    }
    x += dx;
    y += dy;
}   
}
```

When i run the program this is my output but nothing happens:

[image]

Comment: your move method doesn't set any of the coordinates of your ball. the only variables getting set are `x, y, dx, dy` which are just local variables of the move function.

Answer (score 1):

As chiliNUT says, the x, y, dx, dy variables that keep direction and position must be class fields, not local variables.

You can add xPos, yPos fields to MyDrawing class to keep the ball´s position 
and dx ControlledBall class to keep direction, for instance:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

//Does the drawing
class MyDrawing extends JPanel {

    private int xpos;
    private int ypos;

    public void setXPos(final int x) {
        this.xpos = x;
    }

    public void setYPos(final int y) {
        this.ypos = y;
    }

    public int getXpos() {
        return xpos;
    }

    public int getYpos() {
        return ypos;
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(final Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        final Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g.setColor(Color.red);
        final Ellipse2D.Double circle = new Ellipse2D.Double(xpos, ypos, 50, 50);
        g2.draw(circle);
        g2.fill(circle);
        final Rectangle box1 = new Rectangle(10, 10, 380, 300);
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g2.draw(box1);
    }
}

// Produces window plus everything inside it
public class ControlledBall extends JFrame {
    private final JButton       flash       = new JButton("Go");
    private final JButton       steady  = new JButton("Stop");
    private final JPanel        panel       = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
    private final MyDrawing drawing = new MyDrawing();
    private final Timer         timer;

    //direction
    private int dx = 3;
    private int dy = 2;

    public ControlledBall() {
        panel.add(flash);
        panel.add(steady);
        this.add(panel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        this.add(drawing, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        drawing.setXPos(300);
        drawing.setYPos(150);
        steady.addActionListener(new SteadyListener());
        final MoveListener ml = new MoveListener();
        flash.addActionListener(ml);
        timer = new Timer(15, ml);
    }

    class MoveListener implements ActionListener {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(final ActionEvent event) {
            if (!timer.isRunning()){
                timer.start();
            }
            move();
        }
    }

    // Stuck what to implement here
    class SteadyListener implements ActionListener {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(final ActionEvent event) {
            if (timer.isRunning()){
                timer.stop();
            }
        }
    }

    private void move() {

        int x = drawing.getXpos();
        int y = drawing.getYpos();
        final int dia = 30;
        if (x + dx < 0 || x + dia + dx > getWidth()) {
            dx *= -1;
        }
        if (y + dy < 0 || y + dia + dy > getHeight()) {
            dy *= -1;
        }
        x += dx;
        y += dy;
        drawing.setXPos(x);
        drawing.setYPos(y);
        repaint();
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final JFrame window = new ControlledBall();
        window.setSize(400, 400);
        window.setTitle("Controlled Ball");
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        window.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```